# Scrollbar canvas is displayed but does not scroll down. Conflict of tabs and frames? How do I resolve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

[image]

Why doesn't the scrollbar go down to the tab X (in Tab1) where the comboboxes are? The scrollbar is displayed, but it does not go down. There are no errors.

On the other hand, if I set scrollable_frame to comboboxes (as I think you should do it right), the comboboxes disappear and are not displayed

What am I doing wrong? Also is there something to fix in the code?  Can you show me the code please? (with comments I may not understand) Thank you

I specify that I use Canvas and that I would like to use the tkinter widgets

```
import tkinter as tk                    
from tkinter import ttk
  
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tab Widget")
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root, style='Custom.TNotebook', width=400, height=220)
  
tab1 = ttk.Notebook(tabControl)
tab2 = ttk.Notebook(tabControl)
  
tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Tab 1')
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='Tab 2')
tabControl.place(x=1, y=1)

#tab 1
a = ttk.Frame(tab1)
canvas = tk.Canvas(a)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(a, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)


combo1=ttk.Combobox(a, width = 18)
combo1.place(x=20, y=20)
combo1['value'] = ["text1", "text2"] 
          
combo2=ttk.Combobox(a, width = 18)
combo2.place(x=20, y=80)
combo2['value'] = ["text1", "text2"] 

combo3=ttk.Combobox(a, width = 18)
combo3.place(x=20, y=140)
combo3['value'] = ["text1", "text2"] 

combo4=ttk.Combobox(a, width = 18)
combo4.place(x=20, y=200)
combo4['value'] = ["text1", "text2"]


a.pack()
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")


b = ttk.Frame(tab1)
tab1.add(a, text="X")
tab1.add(b, text="Y")


#tab 2
c = ttk.Frame(tab2)
d = ttk.Frame(tab2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you have written, the container widget of the comboboxes is `a`. In this case, the comboboxes are displayed but the scrollbar does not work because the scrollbar is linked to `scrollable_frame`, not `a`.

Now, even if you change the container widget to `scrollable_frame`, it still doesn't work because you have not given a `width` and `height` for `scrollable_frame`. Therefore, `scrollable_frame` appears as a dot. (I figured this out by changing it to a `tk.Frame` and then giving `bg = "blue"`. The frame appeared as a blue dot.)

Also, remember that you need to give a value for `height` greater than the available height in `canvas` to make the scrollbar work.

**Working Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk                    
from tkinter import ttk
  
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tab Widget")
#root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root, style='Custom.TNotebook', width=400, height=220)
  
tab1 = ttk.Notebook(tabControl)
tab2 = ttk.Notebook(tabControl)
  
tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Tab 1')
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='Tab 2')
tabControl.place(x=1, y=1)

#tab 1
a = ttk.Frame(tab1)
canvas = tk.Canvas(a)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(a, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas, width = 500, height = 500)

scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

combo1=ttk.Combobox(scrollable_frame, width = 18)
combo1.place(x=20, y=20)
combo1['value'] = ["text1", "text2"] 
          
combo2=ttk.Combobox(scrollable_frame, width = 18)
combo2.place(x=20, y=80)
combo2['value'] = ["text1", "text2"] 

combo3=ttk.Combobox(scrollable_frame, width = 18)
combo3.place(x=20, y=140)
combo3['value'] = ["text1", "text2"] 

combo4=ttk.Combobox(scrollable_frame, width = 18)
combo4.place(x=20, y=200)
combo4['value'] = ["text1", "text2"]


a.pack()
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")


b = ttk.Frame(tab1)
tab1.add(a, text="X")
tab1.add(b, text="Y")


#tab 2
c = ttk.Frame(tab2)
d = ttk.Frame(tab2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not necessary to call `a.pack()`.

Comment: @Sriram Srinivasan Thanks you. Before voting for it and accepting it as the best answer, I wanted to ask you: 1. What is scrollable_frame.bind and its content for? What is its purpose? I had copied the code from the web so I don't know what that is
scrollable_frame.bind. 2 Is my tab1.add (a, text = "X") correct positioned in the staff where I wrote it? Or should I place it higher ?. 3. Did I write the code clearly and neatly? (I'm referring to the order of the lines, the lines that come before or after) or can some small improvements be applied? If so, can you arrange the order of the lines?

Comment: `canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all"))` tells tkinter what part of `canvas` should be scrollable. "all" refers to the entire content of `canvas`.  The outer statement `scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", ...)` modifies `scrollregion` every time the size of `scrollable_frame` changes. Instead of using the outer statement, you can directly use the inner statement after all the comboboxes have been added. But in general, the outer statement is very useful for frames that change size dynamically. For more information, you can use [this](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html).

Comment: I am not too familiar with the `Notebook` widget. But in my opinion, first creating a frame for a tab and then adding that frame to the tab makes sense. Also, your code was mostly clear except for the variable names a, b, c and d.